# Finding power functions minus 1 on OCaml

Tags: function, ocaml

I wrote a function that finds power. But I want to program to find minus 1 of power function. How can I do that ? For example power 3 4 = 80, power 2 3 = 7
Here is the code

```
let rec power m n =
if n = 0 then 1
else m * power m (n-1) ;;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you'll have to subtract 1 after calculating the power then:

```
let powerMinus1 m n = (power m n) - 1;;
```

Or if you need it self-contained you can use an inner function:

```
let powerMinus1 m n =
  let rec power n =
    ...
  in (power n) - 1;;
```